# Feature level data table in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a situation where I need to have multiple scenarios within the same feature file and I need them to share the data table so that the user need not enter the same test data in all the relevant data tables in that feature.

Eg:

```
Feature: ABC

Scenario : 1
<<Steps of Scenario>>
Enter the data here:
|fieldNickName|fieldValue|
|ABC          | <aaa>      |
<<Steps of Scenario>>
Examples:
|AAA|
|111|

Scenario : 2
<<Steps of Scenario>>
Enter the data here:
|fieldNickName|fieldValue|
|ABC          | <aaa>    |
|DEF          | <bbb>    |
<<Steps of Scenario>>
|HIJ          | <ccc>    |
<<Steps of Scenario>>
Examples:
|AAA|BBB|CCC|
|111|232|AJ|
```

Here as you can see, "ABC" is a shared parameter & AAA its value between both scenarios. Is there a way I can have a "COMMON" Examples section for a Feature which can feed to all the scenarios in it?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to take the examples out of the feature and push them down into the step definitions. I could explain this in greater details if you provided the actual scenarios with their steps and explained the business context behind them.

Your cuking can be much simpler if avoid using examples and outlines. There really is no need to make things so complicated. Scenarios should be clear, simple and descriptive. They should talk about WHAT you are doing not HOW it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way for having the common Example parameters. I am not sure about your scenario but if you are using the same step with same data in all the scenarios, you can make them a part of **Background**

Comment: A `Background` is a (set of) step(s) that will run before each scenario. I'm not sure that answers your question.